# Cannot access proper firebase item key to pass to delete function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, firebase

Having a sticky issue with firebase. I am trying to get access to the long format ID which firebase auto-generates for each collection item (eg. -JgnIsMlTLaPuDMEtQP2) to pass to my delete function. I previously got it to work in a different angular app as follows:

HTML

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key,employee) in employees">
        <tr>
            <td>{{employee.employeeName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.employeeAge}}</td>
            <td>{{key}}</td> // the key param appeared perfectly in this case
            <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" 
                ng-click="deleteEmployee(key, employee.employeeName)">
                delete <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Javascript

```
    $scope.deleteEmployee = function(key,name) {
      // get ref to db collectionvar employeeRef = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/Employees");
      // append item key to the path and run remove method
      var newRef = employeeRef.child(key);
      newRef.remove();
      // confirm delete
      alert(name + " has been deleted");    
    }
```

The above code receives the correctly formatted key and deletes the item perfectly - which is immediately reflected in the view.

However, I'm trying it with a different app and the key value is being set to an incremental index (eg. 0,1,2,3,4...) and so it doesn't work when passed to the delete function. Here is the new code.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <ul id="messages" ng-show="messages.length">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, message) in messages | reverse">{{message.text}}
            <small>{{key}}</small> // WRONG VALUE DISPLAYED HERE
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="delMessage(key)" label="Remove">Delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//delete message 
$scope.delMessage = function(messageKey) {
  var messageRef = new Firebase('https://xxxxxx.firebaseio-demo.com/messages/');
      // append item key to the path and run remove method
  var messageRef = messageRef.child(messageKey);
  if( messageRef ) {
    messageRef.remove();
    console.log("DEL: " + messageRef); // this logs the endpoint with index number 
    console.log("Message removed successfully!");
  } else {
    console.log("uh oh...problem!");
  }
};
```

The format of messageRef when logged to console is

```
https://xxxxxx.firebaseio-demo.com/messages/2
```

but instead should be

```
https://xxxxxx.firebaseio-demo.com/messages/-JgnIsMlTLaPuDMEtQP2
```

I have tried every combination that I could find to get it to work but nothing fixes it so far. I'm not sure why it would work in the first piece of code and not the second. The only thing I can add is the app that isn't working was created via firebase-tools in the terminal whereas the working app is just some angular code with firebase bolted on. I have also tried changing remove() to $remove but that throws undefined method errors. I'm totally stumped. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at AngularFire? That is Firebase's own binding for AngularJS and it solves many of the mapping problems, such as the one you seem to have: mapping Firebase's auto-generated keys to array indices (which AngularJS needs).

Comment: @Frankvan van Puffelen - thanks for response. I'm pretty sure angularFire is baked in as part of a service when the app was generated so should work automatically. However, it still throws error when I use $remove. I'm going to dig around a bit further in the docs to see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Following Frankvan's advice I sourced a snippet from [angularFire quickstart docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html) which allowed me to simply pass the current selected message directly to angularFire's $remove method, avoiding the need to pass a specific message id.

```
  <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
      .......
    <!-- delete message -->
    <button ng-click="messages.$remove(message)">X</button>
  </li>
```

Even though this works, I wanted to add some extra code and decouple the JS from the HTML a bit more. I decided to set up a custom function in the angular controller to handle it and call this function from the ng-click.

The following code works exactly the same as above but adds a prompt for the user to confirm the delete before calling the $remove.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="deleteMessage(message)">x</button>
```

Angular function:

```
 // delete a specific message 
$scope.deleteMessage = function(message) {
  var msg = JSON.stringify(message.text);
  if(message) {
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: " + msg + "?");
    if(confirm == true) {
      $scope.messages.$remove(message).then(function(){
        alert("Message " + msg + " has been deleted!");
        console.log("Message was removed successfully from firebase!");
      });
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry, there was a problem deleting the message.!");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I beat my head against this problem on a project of mine for awhile. The key is to use the $loaded method of Angular Fire to wait for the object to get populated prior to calling the $remove method because these calls are asynchronous.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded